# Issue where min-height and bottom margins add extra space on Chrome (Collpasing Margins)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

In Chrome I noticed when I gave my footer a min-height that the footer is given extra space because of the items inside it with a margin-bottom applied, this only happens in Chrome. It is also fixed by giving the container a fixed height instead og min-height. However I don't want this as I want the container to "grow" if needed.

I tried giving the container divs a border but nothing happened.

Is there an easy fix for collpasing margins?

Here is my code, the element affected by min-height has class "footer_kal_big_container":

```css
.footer_kal_maincontainer{width:100%; height:auto; padding:0px 0px; display:flex; flex-direction:column; background-color:#222222;}
.footer_kal_title{width:100%; height:200px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 75px; justify-content:center; font-size:30px; color:white;}
.footer_kal_big_container{width:100%; min-height:300px; display:flex; padding:25px 75px;}
.footer_kal_big_bio_container{width:33.33%; height:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:0px 15px;}
.footer_kal_big_bio_title{font-size:17px; color:white; margin-bottom:30px;}
.footer_kal_big_bio_paragraph{font-size:14px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); margin-bottom:15px;}
.footer_kal_big_links_container{width:33.33%; height:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.footer_kal_big_links_title{font-size:17px; color:white; margin-bottom:30px;}
.footer_kal_big_links_link{font-size:14px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); margin-bottom:15px; align-self:flex-start;}
.footer_kal_big_contact_container{width:33.33%; height:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.footer_kal_big_contact_title{font-size:17px; color:white; margin-bottom:30px;}
.footer_kal_big_contact_links_container{height:20px; margin-bottom:15px; display:flex; align-items:center; align-self:flex-start;}
.footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_container{width:20px; height:20px; display:flex; margin-right:15px;}
.footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_container .fa{margin:auto; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); font-size:20px;}
.footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_text{font-size:14px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}
.footer_kal_social_container{width:100%; height:100px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 75px; justify-content:center; z-index:99999; box-shadow:0px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.footer_kal_social_icon{margin:0px 15px;}
.footer_kal_social_icon .fab{font-size:35px; color:white; margin:auto;}
.footer_kal_copyright_container{width:100%; height:50px; background-color:white; display:flex; align-items:center; border-bottom:4px solid var(--web_primary_color); padding:0px 75px;}
.footer_kal_copyright_text{font-size:12px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
.footer_kal_design_text{font-size:12px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin-left:auto;}
.footer_kal_design_text .fa{font-size:12px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); padding-left:5px;}
```

```html
<footer class="footer_kal_maincontainer" style="">
    <span class="footer_kal_title" style="">{{ Config::get('globals.web_name') }}</span>
    <div class="footer_kal_big_container" style="">
        <div class="footer_kal_big_bio_container" style="">
         <span class="footer_kal_big_bio_title" style="">Bio</span>
      <p class="footer_kal_big_bio_paragraph" style="">Descripcion sobre nosotros</p>
     </div>
     <div class="footer_kal_big_links_container" style="">
         <span class="footer_kal_big_links_title" style="">Enlaces</span>
      <a class="footer_kal_big_links_link" href="/nuestra-carta-de-menus" style="">Nuestro menu</a>
      <a class="footer_kal_big_links_link" href="/horario de apertura" style="">Horario de apertura</a>
      <a class="footer_kal_big_links_link" href="/localizacion" style="">Localización</a>
   <a class="footer_kal_big_links_link" href="/opiniones-de-nuestros-clientes" style="">Opiniones de nuestros clientes</a>
     </div>
     <div class="footer_kal_big_contact_container" style="">
         <span class="footer_kal_big_contact_title" style="">Contactar</span>
      <a class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_container" href="" style="">
       <div class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_container" style=""><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt" style=""></i></div>
    <span class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_text" style="">{{ Config::get('globals.street') }} . {{ Config::get('globals.city') }}, {{ Config::get('globals.zip_code') }}</span>
   </a>
      <a class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_container" href="tel:{{ Config::get('globals.booking_phone') }}" style="">
       <div class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_container" style=""><i class="fa fa-phone" style=""></i></div>
    <span class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_text" style="">{{ Config::get('globals.booking_phone') }}</span>
   </a>
   <a class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_container" href="mailto:{{ Config::get('globals.customer_mail') }}" style="">
       <div class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_container" style=""><i class="fa fa-at" style=""></i></div>
    <span class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_text" style="">{{ Config::get('globals.customer_mail') }}</span>
   </a>
   <a class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_container" href="/contacta-con-nosotros" style="">
       <div class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_container" style=""><i class="fa fa-envelope" style=""></i></div>
    <span class="footer_kal_big_contact_links_icon_text" style="">Formulario de contacto</span>
   </a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_kal_social_container" style="">
        <a class="footer_kal_social_icon" href="{{ Config::get('globals.tripadvisor') }}" style="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-tripadvisor" style=""></i></a>
     <a class="footer_kal_social_icon" href="{{ Config::get('globals.yelp') }}" style="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-yelp" style=""></i></a>
     <a class="footer_kal_social_icon" href="{{ Config::get('globals.facebook') }}" style="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook" style=""></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_kal_copyright_container" style="">
        <span class="footer_kal_copyright_text" style="">Copyright © {{ now()->year }} {{ Config::get('globals.web_name') }}.</span>
        <span class="footer_kal_design_text">Diseño Web por {{ Config::get('globals.web_author') }} <i class="fa fa-paint-brush "></i></span>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: That is how `min-height` works -- it can be expanded whenever browser decides it is necessary, so when children want parent to expand, it expands. I don't understand what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: That's not how min-height works, the container should expand if the content is larger than the container, in this case it's not larger bt the browser adds unneccesary space to the footer, this doesn't happen in FIrefox